# I want to show mask on an image panel and set particular mask massage on it or set icon on the top-left corner of the image

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to show mask on an image panel and set particular mask massage on it or set icon on the top-left corner of the image. extjs.

```
                {
                xtype: 'form',
                layout: 'hbox',
                width:'100%',
                bodyPadding : '30 20 30 20',
                scrollable:true,
                items : [{
                    xtype:'image',
                  src: imageUrl,
                //    data:'shubham',
                  cls: 'partner-image-wrapper',
                  labelCls:'https:--------------.png'
                  listeners:{
                      render:function(form){debugger
                          form.getEl().dom.addEventListener('mouseenter',function(){debugger
                              form.el.mask('shubhan');
                                         });
                          form.getEl().dom.addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){debugger
                              form.el.unmask();
                                         });
                      }
                  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, you want to show [`mask`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-mask) on image with custom `message`.

You need to use [`image`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.Img.html) component inside [`panel`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.panel.Panel.html) or  any other component.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ar3)**, I have created a demo using ExtJS 5.x version. it will work for all version(4.x or above). I hope this will help you or guide you to achieve your requirement.

**code snippet**

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    title: 'Mask example with image and panel',
    bodyPadding: 5,
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'center'
    },
    items: [{
        layout: 'hbox',
        bodyPadding: 7,
        itemId: 'myImagePnl',
        maxWidth: 320,
        items: [{
            height: 280,
            width: 280,
            xtype: 'image',
            src: 'data:image/png;base64,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'
        }],
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function (panel) {
                panel.mon(panel.body, 'mouseenter', function () {
                    this.up('form').doMaskUnMaskMouseEnterOrLeave(true);
                }, panel);
            }
        }
    }],

    // Mask and Unmask buttons
    bbar: ['->', {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Mask on Image',
        itemId: 'mask',
        handler: function () {
            this.up('form').doMaskUnMask(this);
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        itemId: 'unmask',
        text: 'Unmask on Image',
        disabled: true,
        handler: function () {
            this.up('form').doMaskUnMask(this);
        }
    }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    //function will do mask or unmask on image panel mouse enter or leave.
    doMaskUnMaskMouseEnterOrLeave: function (isMask) {
        var form = this;
        if (isMask) {
            form.down('#myImagePnl').mask('Mouse enter, for unmask leave mouse from <b>image<b>');
            var dom = Ext.DomQuery.select('div.x-mask-msg-text')[0].offsetParent;
            if (Ext.get(dom)) {
                Ext.get(dom).on('mouseleave', function () {
                    this.doMaskUnMaskMouseEnterOrLeave(false);
                }, form);
            }
        } else {
            form.down('#myImagePnl').unmask();
        }
    },
    //function will do mask or unmask on image panel.
    doMaskUnMask: function (btn) {
        var form = this;
        btn.setDisabled(true);
        if (btn.getItemId() == 'mask') {
            form.down('#myImagePnl').mask('Mask button clicked, For unmask click to <b>unmask</b> button');
            form.down('#unmask').setDisabled(false);
        } else {
            form.down('#myImagePnl').unmask();
            form.down('#mask').setDisabled(false);
        }
    }
});
```

**CSS Part**

```
<style>
    .x-mask-msg {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #00000024;
    }

    .x-mask-msg-inner {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;
    }

    .x-mask-msg-text {
        padding: 21px 0 20px 20px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: table-cell;
        color: blue;
        background-size: 0px;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: MY REQUIREMENT IS:1.i want this functionality on mouseenter and mouseleave .2.remove that unwanted loading circle. also try to put a small icon on top left corner .Thanks for this answer Njdhv.

Comment: Please see my answer I have updated and also visit [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ar3).

1) For `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` done.
2) depend on you, you can hide or you can put your `icon`